# Toggling audio and animation of div on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, audio, toggle

Please see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/2CkBY/1/

1. The present code triggers audios and animations to play and pause by mouse enter and mouse leave events.
2. I want to change this code so that the audio and animation is triggered by click events.
3. How do I change the below code to do what I have explained above.

Please note, this is a simplified version in the original there are eight bars altogether.

```
$('#one').mouseenter(function(){
 $('.alt0').animate({width: $(this).width()},
       ($(this).width())/2*1000,"linear",function(){
    $("#refresh-1").show();
    })
});
$('#refresh-1').click(function(){
$('.alt0').width(0);
$(this).hide();
})
$('#one').mouseleave(function(){
 $('.alt0').stop()
});
$('#two').mouseenter(function(){
 $('.alt1').animate({width: $(this).width()},  
 ($(this).width())/2*1000,"linear",function(){
    $('#refresh-2').show();
})
});
$('#refresh-2').click(function(){
$('.alt1').width(0);
$(this).hide();
})
$('#two').mouseleave(function(){
 $('.alt1').stop()
});

$("#one").mouseenter(function () {
$('#sound-1').get(0).play();
});
$("#one").mouseleave(function () {
$('#sound-1').get(0).pause();
});
$("#two").mouseenter(function () {
$('#sound-2').get(0).play();
});
$("#two").mouseleave(function () {
$('#sound-2').get(0).pause();
});
```

Comment: Maybe reformulate this to an actual question?

Comment: i agree the description is crazy try to put it on a list 1. .... 2.... 3.... what happen what you want happen instead

Comment: ech... angela will you write more extended problem/question ??